# how to add existing project in git using bluemix

Tags: git, github, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have a local web application running on node.js,mongodb, which I had pushed/hosted on

bluemix using CF(cloud foundary), now I wantit to integrate it to GIT,so I had clicked add

git button on my dashboard for this project,but I dint find my all code after integration.How

to do that?Cant I add my code to GIT directly through BLUEMIX using ADD GIT option?? or the

only way is to clone that sample git code on my local and edit it accordingly and again

commit for getting changes effective??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is like you mention, sample first to GIT on your local and commit to GIT with your changes.

Then you can push the application based on your GIT. The "add GIT" is to associate a Bluemix Application with a GIT Repository. Pushing changes to this repository will trigger automatic deployment to the application.

As it is mentioned in the documentation:

"The starter code for this application is not currently available, so an empty Git repository will be created."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

currently I see the only way is to clone that sample git code on your local setup, edit all the

relevant files which is needed for you app and then push it using cf tool, your changes will be

effective in that case. There is no way to "add existing code to GIT directly through BLUEMIX using

ADD GIT option".

hope it clears your doubt!!

Answer (score 1):

The only way is you have to create a sample git structure using create git repository from bluemix UI,after than you need to clone that sample to local using git and you have to modify that with your changes,later that you can push it via commit and reflect the changes to bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also push your code to DevOps Services (http://jazzhub.com) and then configure the pipeline there to deploy your code.  If you do it this way it will also associate your git project to your app in Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix has a option to bind services to IBM DevOps Services . You can check these threads.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/19233/deploy-an-existing-project-into-ibm-bluemix.html

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/12070/what-is-correct-workflow-when-using-git-integration-with-bluemix-and-devops-services-jazzhub.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video tutorial on how to do it using Eclipe and DevOps Services. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2W4iqLXciE&list=PLvsG7O_a5F2dAjsNp6aRACP6vkqdgsZ33